# Rails 4.2: how to exclude performance tests during normal test runs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have tests in `test/performance` that used to run only during `rake test:benchmark`. Since upgrading to **Rails 4.2**, the performance tests also seem to run during `rake test`.

What's the best way to exclude `test/performance` tests from normal test runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could either redefine the test task or create a new one with only the test suites you want.

have a look at the PR changing it https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/17348